# Boost C++ regex - how to get multiple matches

Tags: c++, regex, boost

If I have a simple regex pattern like   "ab."  and I have a string that has multiple matches like  "abc abd".  If I do the following...

```
boost::match_flag_type flags = boost::match_default;
boost::cmatch mcMatch;
boost::regex_search("abc abd", mcMatch, "ab.", flags)
```

Then mcMatch contains just the first "abc" result.  How can I get all possible matches?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `boost::sregex_token_iterator` like in this short example:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string text("abc abd");
    boost::regex regex("ab.");

    boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(text.begin(), text.end(), regex, 0);
    boost::sregex_token_iterator end;

    for( ; iter != end; ++iter ) {
        std::cout<<*iter<<'\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
abc
abd
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  Question, what does *iter return, it doesn't appear to be a boost::cmatch in my quick test?  I just gave a very simple example.  In my regex I may have groups, so I need access to the group information for each match (as is available from cmatch)?

Comment: You could try out the regex_iterator instead, it returns a match_result when dereferenced, and should give you what you're looking for?