# extract all dash separated digits using boost regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

i want to extract all dash separated digits ( like this 232-65  ) from string in c++ using boost regex
i use this pattern

```
\\d*-\\d*
```

but only first match is detected. what should i do to extract all matched pattern.

example  input :

```
"2 1 5-25 37 42 43 53 69-119 123-514"
```

out put is only 5-25 but must be 5-25 69-119 123-514

my sample code is

```
    cmatch res;

boost::regex port("\\d*-\\d*");

regex_search(s,res, port);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i) {
    cout << res[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for C++11, but you should be able to replace the `std::` with `boost::` to make it work with Boost

```
std::string s = std::string("2 1 5-25 37 42 43 53 69-119 123-514");

std::regex port("\\d*-\\d*");
std::sregex_token_iterator iter(s.begin(), s.end(), port);
std::sregex_token_iterator end;

for(; iter != end; ++iter) 
{
    std::cout << iter->str() << std::endl;
}
```

Taken from [Boost C++ regex - how to get multiple matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122344/boost-c-regex-how-to-get-multiple-matches)

If you want to use `const char*` it should be:

```
const char *s = "2 1 5-25 37 42 43 53 69-119 123-514";

std::regex port("\\d*-\\d*");
std::cregex_token_iterator iter(s, s + strlen(s), port);
std::cregex_token_iterator end;

for(; iter != end; ++iter) 
{
    std::cout << iter->str() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to embed parenthesised "subexpressions" in your regular expression, which will be extracted in the matching process.  Go read the boost page, searching for subexpression matches....