# Boost Regex unknown number of var

Tags: regex, boost, boost-regex

I have an issue with a regex expression and need some help. I have some expressions like these in mein .txt File:

```
19 = NAND (1, 19)
```

regex expression :  http://rubular.com/r/U8rO09bvTO

With this regex expression I got seperated matches for the numbers.
But now I need a regex expression with an unknown amount of numbers in the bracket.

For example:

```
19 = NAND (1, 23, 13, 24)
```

match1: 19, match2: 1, match3: 23, match4: 13, match5: 24

I don't know the number of the numbers. So I need a main expression for min 2 numbers in the bracket till a unknow number.

By the way i'm using c++.
@ Martjin Your first regex expression worked very well thanks.
Here my code:

```
    boost::cmatch result;
    boost::regex matchNand ("([0-9]*) = NAND\\((.*?)\\)");
    boost::regex matchNumb ("(\\d+)");
    string cstring = "19 = NAND (1, 23, 13, 24)";
    boost::regex_search(cstring.c_str(), result, matchNand);
    cout << "NAND: " << result[1] << "=" << result[2] << endl;
    string str = result[2];
    boost::regex_search(str.c_str(), result, matchNumb);
    cout << "NUM: " << result[1] << "," << result[2]<< "," << result[3] << "," << result[4] << endl;
```

My output:
        NAND: 19=1, 23, 13, 24
        NUM: 1,,,

So my new problem is i only find the first number.
The result is also in complete opposite with this solution: http://rubular.com/r/nqXDSuBXjc

Answer (score 1):

A simple (and maybe more clear than one regex) is to split this into two regexes.

First run a regex that splits your result from your arguments:
http://rubular.com/r/YkGdkkg4y3

```
([0-9]*) = NAND \((.*?)\)
```

Then perform a regex that will match all the numbers in your argument: http://rubular.com/r/2vpSbZvz12

```
\d+
```

Assuming you're using Ruby, you can perform a regex that matches multiple times with the function `scan` as explained here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan

Of course you could just use the second regex with the `scan` function to get all the numbers from that line, but I'm guessing you're going to expand it even more, which is when this approach will be a little more structured.

Comment: thanks for the help now i have a new problem you can see it above

Comment: I'm not well versed in c++, but here's maybe some help:
The function regex_search seems to only search for the regex once, and it will store every group `(..)` in the result array. Since our regex only has one group, it will only populate `result[0]`. 
How to get multiple matches was described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122344/boost-c-regex-how-to-get-multiple-matches

Comment: I see now that the documentation also has an example on how to perform multiple matches, at the examples section: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html